# Copy referenced object and call virtual method C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Here `MyLineShape` object `b` is passed by reference to this function (in `MyCustomWidget` class): and `myShape` is a `Shapes` pointer.

```
void MyCustomWidget::setDrawingObject(Shapes &b){
   myShape = &b;
   myShape->setPoint1();
}
```

It works i.e it calls myShapes setPoint1() method. But when in other part of this MyCustomWidget class I try to use

```
myShape->setPoint1();
```

the program crashes. Maybe this is because of scope? `setPoint1()` is a virtual function as different shape classes implements it separately. So what I am trying to do is in `setDrawingObject` function to tell which object it has received from reference and make a copy of that type of object for later use in this class's other function call. How to do that?

Comment: What kind of error message do you get when your program crashes? Can you show us the function where your program crashes? It would help alot.

Comment: please have a look at this: github.com/adolescent/WaterPaint.git on shapeClasses branch. File to look at is mainwindow.cpp and MyCustomWiget.cpp

Comment: You said "But when in other part of this MyCustomWidget class". What part of your code crashes? Please detail your explanation.

Comment: You are not copying the referenced object, you are taking its address.

Comment: @Cubia in mousevent methods when I try to use myShape->setPoint1()

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just have a dangling pointer. Whatever object you're calling `setDrawingObject` is getting destroyed while you still have a pointer to it. There are two common approaches to solving this problem. First, just use `shared_ptr`:

```
void MyCustomWidget::setDrawingObject(shared_ptr<Shapes> b) {
   myShape = b;
   myShape->setPoint1();
}
```

The second would be to add a `virtual` `clone()` member function to `Shapes` that you would all here to make a copy. So something like:

```
void MyCustomWidget::setDrawingObject(Shapes& b) {
    myShape.reset(b.clone());  // myShape is a unique_ptr<Shapes>
    myShape->setPoine1();
}
```

Either way, avoid having `myShape` simply be a `Shapes*`.

Comment: @eagleye [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset). And no, I am not debugging your entire project for you. If you want to ask another question, ask another question.

Comment: not that I thought it would be easier for you to understand. I will try  more and let you know